# peer chain code install problem directory not found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have started a fabric network with three orgs one pear for each org and one orderer. Created one channel and added the peers to the channel.But when i try to install the chaincode it says directory not found. I also mounted the volume inside my cli config. 
i am entering cli bash before entering the command also checked using peer channel list command to see if my peer is joined in a channel.

my cli config

```
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/fabric-samples/food-network/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/fabric-samples/food-network/crypto-config/
```

my peer command

```
 peer chaincode install -n chain  chain -v 1.0
```

error

```
Error: open /opt/gopath/fabric-samples/food-network/chaincode/chain: no such file or directory
```

my chain code  is named chain.go. Its a go file and it has been built.

also when i try this command:

```
peer chaincode install -n chain -p chain -v 1.0
```

it gives this error:

```
 error getting chaincode code chain: path to chaincode does not exist: /opt/gopath/src/chain
```

Comment: create "chain" directory under "chaincode" directory and copy your chain.go in "chain" directory. After that map the new directory in "volume" and try the same command.

Comment: Error: open chain: no such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install chaincode, you need to build a chaincode package.  You can either run

```
peer chaincode package ...
```

followed by

```
peer chaincode install ...
```

or you can use the `-p` option with `peer chaincode install` to package and install together.

When using the peer cli to package chaincode, it will look for your Go chaincode under `$GOPATH/src`.  The cli container has its `GOPATH` set to `/opt/gopath`.

I'm not sure where your actual chaincode is located, but assuming your your Go code is located in `./../chaincode` on your host, you would need to change your volume mount to

```
- ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode
```

and then you can run

```
peer chaincode install -n chain -p chaincode -v 1.0
```

Comment: i installed the chaincode after changing the directory but when i try to initiate the chaincode with this command `eer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.food-network.com:7050 -C channelshovon -n chain -v 0  -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('ImporterMSP.member')"
`  it gives error and when i check the logs it gives this error `cannot get package for chaincode (chain:0)-err:open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/chain.0: no such file or directory
`

Comment: when i check the peer for installed chain code it shows that chain v0 is installed